# c++ virtual inheritance initialization order

Tags: c++, virtual, multiple-inheritance

[image]

Hi,
As you can see the Construction order in the example is: – **U1 U2 Y X V2 V1 V3 V4 B1 B2 D**

I understand that : **U1 U2 Y X** were initialized because the **V2** is the first direct virtual inheritance to D, and in order to initialize it there is need to initialize these first **U1 U2 Y X** . After that **V2** was initialized , but why **V1** is initialized before **V3** although there is direct virtual inheritance from **V3** .

Please ignore the numbers of the nodes and arrows and notice that red arrow is non virtual inheritance and black arrow is virtual.

*Note: original document may be found [there](http://webcourse.cs.technion.ac.il/236703/Winter2012-2013/ho/WCFiles/12%2520-%2520Multiple%2520Inheritance%2520-%2520c%2B%2B11.pdf).*

Comment: @Basile No, why? That’s nonsense, the question is perfectly on topic.

Comment: @Basile ,It is not off topic question, and it does not need code to understand the question or to post in stackoverflow, this is an understanding question of the C++ virtual inheritance , graph is the easiest way to understand the concept, please ignore the question if you don't know the answer.

Comment: I'd like to downvote the creator of that graph, but not the OP.

Comment: Wh... what is that graph?!?

Comment: @NikBougalis that graph is the last page here: http://webcourse.cs.technion.ac.il/236703/Winter2012-2013/ho/WCFiles/12%20-%20Multiple%20Inheritance%20-%20c++11.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my understanding of the example. It matches the construction order, so I believe it to be correct. However, I'm not certain.

First off, the numbers of the arrows are important because they tell you the order in which the base classes are defined. Just using `D` as an example, the class is defined as so:

```
class D : virtual V2, B1, B2, virtual v3 {...}
```

Given that, my next step is to traverse the graph and put all the classes into depth-first order regardless of whether they are virtual or not. Braces indicate a base class. Parentheses indicate a virtual base class that is already in my class list:

```
D {V2 {X {U1, U2}, Y {(U2), (U1)}}, B1 {V1, (V2), V3 {(Y), (U2)}, V4}, B2 {(V4-V1)}, (V3)
```

To me this says

- To construct D, first I need V2.
- V2 needs X, which needs U1 and U2.
- Next V2 needs Y, which needs U2 and U1, but both are already in my list.
- Next D needs B1.
- B1 needs V1, V2, V3 and V4, with V2 already in my list.
- V3 needs Y and U2, but both are already in my list.
- Next D needs B2, which needs V4 through V1, all already in my list.
- Finally, D needs V3, but again, it is already in my list.

Given that, I'll now remove the redundant base classes, leaving this:

```
D {V2 {X {U1, U2}, Y}, B1 {V1, V3, V4}, B2}
```

The next part is to find the non-virtual base classes and make adjustments to my list.

- V2 needs X and Y, where Y is virtual, so Y will have to come before X.

An extra point about this: Given your question, I would expect you to also think that U2 should come before U1 because Y is constructed before X and in Y, U2 is derived first. However, that does not happen. Instead, X's virtual base classes are done in order, then Y, and finally X.

This adjusts my list to the following:

```
D {V2 { {U1, U2}, Y, X}, B1 {V1, V3, V4}, B2}
```

Finally, B1 is non-virtual, so it needs to come after V1, V3 and V4. This leaves:

```
D {V2 { {U1, U2}, Y, X}, {V1, V3, V4}, B1, B2}
```

Note that B2 is also non-virtual and would need to be considered if it wasn't already last in my list.

This gives me an order that I am happy with. The only problem is that I am listing derived classes before base classes, and we know that base classes are constructed first. The only two places left where this is an issue are

- D, which needs to be last.
- V2, which needs to be after its children.

So I'll adjust my list to move these two items, V2 after X, and D after B2.

```
{ { {U1, U2}, Y, X} V2, {V1, V3, V4}, B1, B2} D
```

Now I'll remove the parentheses and:

```
U1, U2, Y, X, V2, V1, V3, V4, B1, B2, D
```

You can see that this matches the order of constructors in the diagram, and does, in fact match the order called when I build with Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, I understand everything until I got to the "extra point", the current is Y , why do we have to init by inheritance order in X , if we are not in X yet!!? Is it because you explored U1 and U2 through X not Y ?

Comment: @nabil, Yes. That is correct. Because V2 is essentially declared as `class V2 : X, virtual Y`, it is required to do the virtual base classes of X in order for X. Then, before getting constructing X, it is required to construct Y because Y is a virtual base class of V2 and X is not. If Y also had a virtual base class that wasn't a base class of X, that would also be required before X.

Comment: My question now is like that , when you said above that "V2 needs X and Y, where Y is virtual, so Y will have to come before X." why we didn't apply that order also on : D when it needed B1 and V3 where V3 is virtual , so V3 will come first ?

Comment: The reason why we didn't apply that order later on with B1 and V3 is because the V3 that you're referring to (direct base class of D) was one of the redundant V3's that was removed from our list. It already existed earlier in the list (as a base class of B1), so V3's first position in the list (under B1) determined its place in the construction order. That position is already before B1, so there is no need to adjust for it.

Answer (score 0):

I will only address your question regarding the order of V1 and V3.

The first step is:

> Apply topological sort ranking inheritance DAG in a **depth-first**, **left-right** scan,
>
> - Virtual and non-virtual inheritance are **treated alike**.

According to this rule V1 comes before V3: V1 is deeper, and to the left of V3, regardless of the inheritance type. The left to right order is defined by the direct inheritance rank of the successive ancestors from D up to the concerned node. That rank is carried by the edges between nodes of the graph (and thus cannot be ignored): V3 has rank (3) while, V2 has rank (1) - and also (2,2) which is cancelled by the higher one - and V1 has rank (2, 1). The order is therefore V2, then V1, then V3, between these 3 nodes.

*Note : the graph doesn't depict the nodes in their correct left right order for clarity, given the number of relationships  V2 and V3 holds with other nodes, whereas V1 doesn't have any ancestor.*

Step 2 is:

> Construct **all** virtual base classes (immediate and non immediate)
>
> - use **ranking order**.
> - do not construct twice
>
> [...]

V1 and V3 are both virtually inherited, V1 for B1, and V3 for D, so they get constructed both at this step, in the order established at step 1.

Comment: Thank you, but if I apply the rules you mentioned above why V2 initialized before V1 , it is the same depth and V1 is to the left of V3.

Comment: the graph visual representation is probably what is misleading there, since as I said V1 is really between V2 and V3 left order wise. That said, I didn't go all the way to explain the entire algorithm execution. The other answer is clearly superior in that regard.